# How to make makefile for MPI program with openMP?

Tags: c, makefile, mpi, openmp

I have absolutely no experience in using makefile for MPI program with OpenMP. I usually run on the command prompt as

```
mpicc main.c -fopenmp -o Out
mpirun -np 4 Out
```

So now I need to utilise the makefile and my understanding is that we use makefile to run the commands in a more convenient way so logically we should type the same commands in the makefile right? So my makefile now looks like this

```
all: 
    mpicc main.c -fopenmp -o Out
    mpirun -np 4 Out
```

Is there a step by step guide on how to create a makefile for absolute beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles are commonly used for build/compile, test, install and uninstall programs and pieces of code. It's not very common to use it to actually run the programs, but yes, you can do it. You can create a specific rule to it, like `run`

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-fopenmp
EXE=./Out
SRCS=main.c

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o $(EXE)

run:
    mpirun -np 4 $(EXE)
```

So you can compile it with just `make` and then invoke it with `make run`

**NOTE:** the space preceding the commands inside a rule must be a tab

> Is there a step by step guide on how to create a makefile for absolute beginner?

You can give a look on [this page from University of Oxford](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/it-services/makefiles-for-beginners)